# What tells the GPU where to store the result of a render operation of a certain application's context?

Tags: graphics, gpu, driver

As the title implies I'm curious what part of a system is responsible for making sure the GPU outputs it's calculated image into the correct framebuffer so that the compositing window manager can use that buffer to produce a final image. Furthermore I'm interested how graphics APIs like Direct3D/OpenGL/Vulkan fit in this model. They can't be communicating directly to the low level graphics driver because then they could avoid the windowing system completely and just paint to the actual framebuffer directly?